# How do I converge taxonomy category permalinks into one?

Tags: taxonomy

My site has many different taxonomies but three taxonomies (Music, Books and Video games) I want the permalink to be /entertainment/. If I use the permalink structure in WP it will also change the other taxonomies as well and I only want to change those three.

What would be the best way of achieve this? I haven't attempted anything yet because I can't seem to find anything that matches my issue on google.

Comment: How about creating a new taxonomy named `entertainment` and under it creating those three terms? Would that be a problem with your current setup?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. We inherited a site from someone else and we are building a new feature that has to follow the way the taxonomy currently is.